# Should I Use Nulls/Blanks to Convey Meaning in a Related Column Representing a Category?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, null

I'm designing a personal database that has a table which contains categories for seasonal events of a video game. In my design I have a related column from `Events` to `Items` (one to many [1:m] respectively). However, whenever there is no event/season going on, I'm not sure whether I should create an special row in my `Events` table to handle such scenarios or just leave the related column of `Items` empty.

I've been researching about the topic and I have several found reasonable arguments for either case (to use or not to use a null), but the problem is that none of what I've read so far is framed in use-case that would apply for my specific dilemma. As a result, I'm now even more confused as to what to do. I was originally going to add a "*Non-Event*" row to my table.

Comment: `NULL` is the "natural" way in SQL to store the absence of information. I personally avoid "magic values" or "magic rows" at all costs

Comment: Additionally - NULL value do not interfere with foreign key reference (if it is not prohibited explicitly), so it does not affect to integrity check.

Comment: Keep in mind also that in general "blank", or empty string, is _not_ the same as null, although sadly not all DBMSes comply.

Comment: @mustaccio I'm on a database course currently, and actually today I found out how nulls are ignored by the `INSERT INTO` statement and blanks are not. In programming I had never seen such a wild interaction change from blanks to nulls.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, that settles it. I'm going to use nulls. Besides, what I didn't add in my question to make it simpler is that, there was a intermediate table between the ones I mentioned that would have had to "inherit" the blank category row. It seems much simpler now.